# Ajuste de tabla en HTML2PDF

Tags: html, css

Estoy generando un pdf mediante HTML2PDF, pero al diseñar el pdf me doy cuenta que mi tabla no se acopla al tamaño de la hoja en PDF...

```
table { 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px 4px 2px 7px;
    text-align: left;           
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dale width exactos en tu css, puedes crear clases a los th y td, y le das el width que necesites
[image]